# How to tell where the texture is drawn in OpenGL / libgdx?

Tags: java, opengl, textures, libgdx, render

How do we know which texture is related to which mesh in OpenGL? In this example, we tell the mesh we use texture coordinates, but we don't say which texture (if we have more than one), and we don't tell the texture where to be drawn. How does it work? (I know the concept of UVs, but I don't know the concept of "where" the texture is drawn) :

```
mesh = new Mesh(true, 4, 6,
     new VertexAttribute(VertexAttributes.Usage.Position, 3,"attr_Position"),
     new VertexAttribute(Usage.TextureCoordinates, 2, "attr_texCoords"));
texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/img.png"));
mesh.setVertices(new float[] { 
      -1024f, -1024f, 0, 0, 1,
       1024f, -1024f, 0, 1, 1,
       1024f,  1024f, 0, 1, 0,
      -1024f,  1024f, 0, 0, 0
});


@Override
public void render() {
    // Texturing --------------------- /
    gl.glActiveTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE0);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    texture.bind();

    mesh.render(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES);
}
```

Comment: Where the texture is drawn == UV Coordinates ... Which texture is used == `glActiveTexture()`

Comment: @Vallentin Thanks Vallentin, UVs are for the texture itself, not where in the world? About activeTexture, could you please tell me how it would be with 2 meshes and a second texture?

Comment: Where in the world, well you specify that using the objects x,y,z coordinates, of course ... If you want to perform "Multi Texturing", basically just bind multiple textures, and use `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);` and then `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);` and so on... Then there are various ways in the Shader to differentiate between which texture to use and when!

Comment: @Vallentin so if you want to switch the texture of a mesh, and you have 2 texture variables... how to tell GL_TEXTURE0 is the first texture and GL_TEXTURE1 is the second texture?

Comment: If you want to just switch the texture of a model/mesh, then simply bind another texture... `glActiveTextureN();` is used for Shaders, and I can't really see your Shader nor if you actually bind the "active id's" to the Shader.

Comment: Would you have an example? I am confused with the ids. It seems `glBindTexture()` also needs an `int` as a second parameter, but I don't know how to replace my texture by an `int` ?

Comment: @Vallentin Thanks Vallentin for your help, I managed to make it work with ArrayList and a counter for the texture, I had no idea how it worked, so I was a bit confused reading the explanations. Thanks for your help, if you want, put an answer with the information you gave and I will select it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I actually found the solution : https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/DecalTest.java